# jquery-ui datepicker and Datepicker for Bootstrap from twwiter

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

what is the different between `jquery-ui datepicker` and `Datepicker for Bootstrap from twitter`
What options give?

Who better to use?

I prefer `Datepicker for Bootstrap from twwiter` because of the way how to choose the year and month, are there things I lose?

Answer (score 2):

The Twitter Bootstrap Datepicker is actually an extension of the original plugin by Stefan Petre. He has gone back to rework the styles which include default classes right out of the Twitter Bootstrap stylesheet. The plugin homepage features a lot of unique demos which are simply stunning. They look nicer using the typical Bootstrap interface designs.

So basically Bootstrap Datepicker has a better look by adding the interface design of the bootstrap.

Please read [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/best-jquery-date-picker-plugins-for-input-fields) article for further clarification